# select between lists elements with regex

Tags: python, string, list

I have 2 lists:

```
images = ['ND_row_id_4026.png',
          'ND_row_id_7693.png',
          'ND_row_id_5285.png',
          'ND_row_id_1045.png',
          'ND_row_id_2135.png',
          'ND_row_id_8155.png',
          'ND_row_id_3135.png']

masks = ['MA_row_id_4026.png',
         'MA_row_id_7693.png',
         'MA_row_id_5285.png',
         'MA_row_id_1045.png',
         'MA_row_id_2135.png']
```

I want to keep the `masks` files. So, I have 2 folders with images and masks and I want to keep all the masks that are in the `masks` list and the corresponding images. The images list is bigger than the masks.

So ,I want to keep from the images list:

```
images = ['ND_row_id_4026.png',
          'ND_row_id_7693.png',
          'ND_row_id_5285.png',
          'ND_row_id_1045.png',
          'ND_row_id_2135.png']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems (*based on your sample data*) a simple list comprehension should suffice, just replacing the prefix for comparison:

```py
res = [im for im in images if im.replace('ND', 'MA') in masks]
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
[
 'ND_row_id_4026.png',
 'ND_row_id_7693.png',
 'ND_row_id_5285.png',
 'ND_row_id_1045.png',
 'ND_row_id_2135.png'
]
```

If your lists are large, it would be more efficient to pre-process the masks array (as it is the smaller of the two):

```
m2 = [ma.replace('MA', 'ND') for ma in masks]
res = [im for im in images if im in m2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
images = [image for image in images if image in [x.replace('MA','ND') for x in masks]]
```

Explanation:

`[...]`: make list

`[image for image in images]`: iterate along images list

`... if image in [..]`: filter the result and only return those who are in the other list.

`[x.replace('MA','ND') for x in masks]`: make list where `MA` is replaced by `ND` in mask

Answer (score 1):

May be this could help you … written using set method

**Code :**

```
import re

images = ['ND_row_id_4026.png',
          'ND_row_id_7693.png',
          'ND_row_id_5285.png',
          'ND_row_id_1045.png',
          'ND_row_id_2135.png',
          'ND_row_id_8155.png',
          'ND_row_id_3135.png']

masks = ['MA_row_id_4026.png',
         'MA_row_id_7693.png',
         'MA_row_id_5285.png',
         'MA_row_id_1045.png',
         'MA_row_id_2135.png']

# Fetching all digits from image file names  
forimages = set( j[0] for j in [ re.findall(r'\d+',val) for val in images ])

# Fetching all digits from mask file names
formasks =  set( j[0] for j in [ re.findall(r'\d+',val) for val in masks ])

# Applying intersection logic on digit to get comma digit between both 
my_mask_data = [ 'ND_row_id_{0}.png'.format(i) for i in sorted(forimages.intersection(formasks)) ]

# Printing the output 
print(my_mask_data)
```

**Output :**

```
['ND_row_id_1045.png', 'ND_row_id_2135.png', 'ND_row_id_4026.png', 'ND_row_id_5285.png', 'ND_row_id_7693.png']
```

Incase if you find any issue in above … feel free to change it